# For which values of the parameter $p$ the following series is convergent?

Tags: calculus

For which values of the parameter $p$ the following series is convergent? 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln^p n } 
$$

First, for $p=0$ , the series doesn't converge. For $p<0$ , the series also diverges, since:
$\ln^p n < n$ which implies: $ \frac{1}{n \ln^p n } \geq \frac{n^{-p}}{n} $ and the series in the RHS diverges,

Will you please help me with the case $p>0$ ?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the Integral Test.

Comment: Will you please show me how ?

Comment: To evaluate $\int{1\over x(\ln x)^p}\,dx$, substitute $u=\ln x$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237015/find-the-values-of-p-for-the-following-check-if-they-are-converges

Answer (score 1):

By [Cauchy's condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), such a series is convergent for any $p>1$, divergent otherwise.